# Get instance of class dynamically in .NetCore

Tags: attributes, asp.net-core, instance

I need class instance from string to check if it has certain Attribute.
I have tried it like this

```
Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetType("ClassName");
object entity = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var tableAttribute = entity.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>();
```

but type is null ?

Entire code in TestConsoleApp:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AssemblyTest
{
    [Description("TestDescription")]
    public class TestClass { }
    //
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetType("TestClass");

            if(type == null)
                Console.WriteLine("Object type is NULL.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Object type has value.");

            object entity = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            var tableAttribute = entity.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your type is in the current assembly and not in a different assembly?

Comment: It's it the same project.
Just create New Project -> .NET Core -> Console Application.
I named it AssemblyTest and I have updated question adding entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying the name of the class you must provide a fully qualified name that includes it's namespace.  So this line needs tweaked:

`Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetType("ClassName");`

If ClassName is in namespace App.Logic then the line should be:

`Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetType("App.Logic.ClassName");`

So given your updated code the line should be:

`Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetType("AssemblyTest.TestClass");`

I have tested it and it does work if a fully qualified class name is used which includes the namespace information.

Comment: Yes it works, I also checked it. Thx.
Just to add another way that you mentioned to get type:
Type type = Type.GetType("AssemblyTest.TestClass");